# Windows update by Ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, yaml

I have tried to installed Windows update with windows10update.exe by Ansible because I cannot use Windows update it has some error with Windows 10 that I used. The playbook work fine everything can run by Ansible but the Windows is not update new version. Any advice?

I have changed some code and it can run but no update change on Windows

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: download the Windows update package
    win_get_url:
      url: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=799445
      dest: C:\Users\win10up.exe

  - name: Ensure Windows update is installed via win_package
    win_package:
      name:
       product_id: HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{D5C69738-B486-402E-85AC-2456D98A64E4}
      path: C:\Users\win10up.exe
      state: present
    register: ins

  - name: Reboot when Update finish
    win_reboot:
    when: ins.reboot_required
```

Comment: Hi kasbertan, welcome to SO. Your question is at risk of closure because it appears to be related to system administration, and not programming topics. You may find more success asking this kind of question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com), which is designed for system administration topics. You will also want to include evidence you have that "the playbook works fine" as well as evidence you have that Windows is not updating, since thus far we just have your assertion, but we cannot possibly use psychic powers to know what's wrong with your systems

Comment: Oh, thanks for suggestion.